# Suffering "Stale" Choices for FilePathField

Tags: django

I have a FilePathField in a form that displays directory contents as
expected. However if I add or remove a file to/from the directory the
change is not updated in the form.

Here is the from:

from django import forms

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    the_file = forms.FilePathField(path='c:/temp')
```

and the corresponding view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from forms import MyForm

def test(request):
    form = MyForm()
    return render_to_response('test.html', {'form' : form})
```

Comment: What if you change the path to a callable?

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: It means that instead of setting the value of `path='c:/temp'` as a string, you would set the value of `path` to a function that returns the path string - a callable.

Comment: Nope that doesn't fix it.  Thanks for your help Brandon I've got another way of going about the same thing this would have just been more robust.

Hopefully Django will get this fixed in the future

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this today, after noticing that new folders weren't being reflected in the select menu.

The [`FilePathField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#filepathfield) is initialized once, when django starts up (when the [`Form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form) class is parsed by python). The contents of the directory are then stored in the field itself, and then persist for the lifetime of the program.

This behavior is unexpected (at least by me) and not explicitly documented.

The discussion below implies that this only happens when a `FilePathField` is used in an explicit Form class, rather than in a dynamically generated ModelForm.

See: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/django-developers/FilePathField$20refresh/django-developers/mHK-9N75swM/3k13dC5HVQoJ

And the relevant bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16429

Neither has received much attention on the forums, so I suspect this falls into edge-case territory, probably because the fixes for it are likely to be messy.

---

*Update* I've implemented a silly workaround. Whenever you need a new form, the `__init__` method is called. In that method, initialize a new `FilePathField` with the same arguments are the original one. The new one will have a fresh copy of the directory entries in it, and replace the stale choices with the fresh copy.

To keep from abusing the file system, keep a copy of these choices around in the cache for 5 seconds.

```
from django import forms
from django.core.cache import cache

class MyAwesomeForm(forms.Form): 
    _filepath_kw = dict(path='/some/dir',
                        label="Path to source images.",
                        recursive=True, allow_files=False,
                        allow_folders=True)

    my_field = forms.FilePathField(**_filepath_kw)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        key = 'filepath-cache-key'
        choices = cache.get(key)
        if not choices:
            field = forms.FilePathField(**self._filepath_kw)
            choices = field.choices
            cache.set(key, choices, 5)

        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.base_fields['source'].choices = choices
```

If your directory is *huge*, storing zillions of file records in the cache is likely quite slow and probably a bad idea.

This will cause validation issues if the file system changes right after the POST, but, that's probably a good thing.

I'm pushing this change to an application this afternoon, so if I find terrible unforeseen consequences I'll update this answer.

Comment: 7 years later I presume nothing bad happened...

Comment: Nope, actually it's been working fine. In my particular case though, the directories in question are on a network share, so the web thread would timeout on _really_ big directories.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use a cache but you were happy with that each time you call this form it reads the actual files or folders, then you could use this solution:

```
class ApproveUpdateForm(forms.Form):
    #to ensure that the file list is updated each time ApproveUpdateForm is called
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.fields['app'] = forms.FilePathField(path=settings.EXAMPLE_EXCH_DIR, match='.*\.tar.gz',
                                             label=_("Application"))
        self.fields['app'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'form-control'
```